# What happens to my files when uninstalling Ubuntu (installed from wubi)

Tags: uninstall

(original OS win7) I've installed ubuntu from wubi (so I can easily uninstall it after I try it), I've also installed some apps.  I am wondering if I uninstall ubuntu, will all the files I created and apps I installed in ubuntu be removed as well or would I have to manually remove them after?

Comment: Please consider accepting fossfreedom's answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

#### yes...

Yes - everything you did within the ubuntu-wubi installation will be removed and lost when you uninstall.

A little explanation will help.

A wubi install is *in layman terms* a rather large file(s) reserved within your NTFS windows 7 installation.  When you uninstall wubi via the *Add/Remove Program* feature of Windows, you are effectively just removing this/these file(s).

Nothing in Windows itself will be removed or *lost* - just the Ubuntu changes.

Best advice is to backup any important files to external media such as CD/DVD or USB.  Make sure you use a media format such as NTFS to allow windows to see it.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate with a diagram(sorry, few freehand circles):

[image]

All red will be destroyed. As you can see, the Ubuntu installation is inside Windows in Wubi, but not in a regular installation.